# Getting Init Failed error when building container for AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, shell, aws-lambda

Building an AWS Lambda function from a Docker Container using [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/) as a base for my project:

However, when I build the container and attempt to run it using SAM, this is the set of errors I get everytime:

```
time="2021-02-19T21:43:03.87" level=error msg="Init failed" InvokeID= error="fork/exec /entry.sh: exec format error"
time="2021-02-19T21:43:03.87" level=error msg="INIT DONE failed: Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint"
```

```
FROM python-alpine
# Copy in the built dependencies
COPY --from=build-image . .
# (Optional) Add Lambda Runtime Interface Emulator and use a script in the ENTRYPOINT for simpler local runs
ADD aws-lambda-rie /usr/bin/aws-lambda-rie
COPY . .
COPY entry.sh /
COPY aws-lambda-rie /usr/bin/
RUN chmod 755 /usr/bin/aws-lambda-rie /entry.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "/entry.sh" ]
CMD ["app.handler"]
```

Above is the last part of the Dockerfile to package everything created in the `build-image` container earlier in the script.

The entry.sh file contents are below. The purpose of the file is to tell the container to run the aws lambda handler function stated in the last line of the Dockerfile.

```
if [ -z "${AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API}" ]; then
    exec /usr/bin/aws-lambda-rie /usr/local/bin/python3 -m awslambdaric $1
else
    exec /usr/local/bin/python3 -m awslambdaric $1
fi
```

If anyone know or has any ideas as to what it could be, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: There are certain parts of the multistage `Dockerfile` you are missing in the code you shared like Installing Lambda Runtime Interface Client for Python `RUN python${RUNTIME_VERSION} -m pip install awslambdaric --target ${FUNCTION_DIR}
`. That's the reason your `entry.sh` is throwing error and failing and showing error for `Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint`